# State that flair shows at most 7 sites

Tags: feature-request, combined-flair

Please make the "flair for user" page say explicitly that the sites and reputation shown are for the 7 top sites for the user. I got confused by that...

Comment: Well, there's no place for more than that since it's fixed width and height but I agree it should be mentioned explicitly.